# how to return only truthy values as the result of a map operation

Tags: clojure

I have a function below to return the vowels. However I would like to only return truthy values, how do I do that ?

```
(map #{\a \e \i \o \u} (seq (char-array "Hello"))) => (nil \e nil nil \o)
```

Answer (score 7):

`filter identity (map f ...` = `(keep f ...`.

```
> (keep #{\a \e \i \o \u} (seq (char-array "Hello")))
(\e \o)
```

Comment: +1, but why `(seq (char-array "Hello"))`? Why not just `"Hello"` for the sake of brevity?

Comment: Because `(seq (char-array "Hello"))` is what the questioner had as the argument, and the question wasn't about that, so why change things up?

Comment: Haha right, that makes sense, guess I should've read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 4):

filter for the non nil ones

```
(filter (comp not nil?)
    (map #{\a \e \i \o \u} (seq (char-array "Hello")))
(\e \o)
```

you can in gneral filter on truthyness like so:

```
 (filter #(if % true false) (map #{\a \e \i \o \u} "Hello"))
 (\e \o)
```

it's worth noting that sets implement a callable interface that returns true if the item is in the set, so you can use a set directly as the predicate to filter so for your initial example the answer can be expressed directly with filter (though that is a different questions)

```
(filter #{\a \e \i \o \u} "Hello")
(\e \o)
```

ps: strings are already sequences so you don't strictly need the `(seq (char-array "Hello"))` bit though it does not really hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but it seems chars are falsy ! But then tried by replacing true? by char? and it worked !

Comment: Chars are not falsy: `(if \o true false) ;=> true`. The predicate `true?` doesn't test for truthiness, it tests whether the value *is the value `true`*. The only two values that aren't truthy in clojure are `nil` and `false`.

Comment: I was misusing the term truthy, sorry. I'll fix that

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is the same as [counting only truthy values in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518320/counting-only-truthy-values-in-a-collection), so use the `identity` function with filter:

```
(filter identity (map #{\a \e \i \o \u} (seq (char-array "Hello")))
```