# counting only truthy values in a collection

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to return only truthy values as the result of a map operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518270/how-to-return-only-truthy-values-as-the-result-of-a-map-operation)

I have a collection which has falsy and truthy values. I would like to only count the truthy values, is there a way to do that ?

> (count (1 2 3 nil nil)) => 5

Comment: not a duplicate - counting values vs. returning them is a different operation (and has some quite different solutions)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to keep the truthy values just need to use the `identity` function:

```
   (count (filter identity '(1 2 3 nil nil false true)))
```

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend doing this with reduce as follows:

```
(defn count-truthy [coll]
  (reduce (fn [cnt val] (if val (inc cnt) cnt)) 0 coll))
```

Reasons for using reduce in this way:

- It is likely to be more efficient, and will benefit from Clojure's new reducers functionality that enables fact reduces on many collections
- It avoids creating an intermediate sequence (which would happen if you used a lazy sequence function like filter)

If you already have a realised sequence, then the following is also a good option, as it will benefit from primitive arithmetic in the loop:

```
(defn count-truthy [coll]
  (loop [s (seq coll) cnt 0]
    (if s
      (recur (next s) (if (first s) (inc cnt) cnt))
      cnt)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove values that you do not want to count.

```
(count (remove nil? [1 2 3 nil nil])) => 3
```

Comment: slight bug: (count (remove nil? [1 2 3 nil nil false])) => 4

Comment: you can fix this by replacing the `nil?` with `#(if % false true)`

Comment: #(if % false true) is absolutely equivalent to the function not. (count (remove not [1 2 3 nil nil false])) returns the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn truthy-count [coll] 
   (reduce + 0 
     (map #(if % 1 0) coll)))
```

Although I admit I like dAni's solution better.

Answer (score 2):

the genral pattern is filter the sequence and count the results

```
(count (filter #(if % %) [1 2 3 nil nil false]))
3
```

the `#(if % %)` is just a short test for truthyness that returns an item only if it is truthy or something falsy (nil) otherwise

Comment: What advantages does this have, if any, over the `(count (filter (identity` approach?

Comment: it's just a different way of expressing the concept of "if this item is truthy" personally I find it more clear though thats just my opinion